# How can I delete Android Studio project located in ionic project?

Tags: javascript, android, angular, ecmascript-6, ionic4

I have an ionic project, and for now the unique platform that i am built for is android, all features in project were working fine, previously when i export to APK this project, also works perfectly, the project in that time already had an android studio project linked in, but despite this everything worked fine.

Recently, looking in a page I saw that a project of ionic can be easily imported in android studio clicking on "Import project (Gradle, Eclipse, ADT, etc.)", so I clicked on that option and looked for my .gradle file.

Once I found it, I opened this in Android Studio, some message was displayed importing the project, something like "This version of gradle seems to be older, we recommend to update gradle, click here to update gradle", so i clicked in, but doesn't install successfully, for other errors...

As I didn't know what to do, I simply closed Android Studio, and tried to build APK once again but from the CMD, my APK was successfully built.

But now when I install the APK, run the APK and try to use the functionality of 2 plugins, one plugin simple doesn't works, but don't close me the application (imagePicker).

In case of the other plugin (googleMaps), when i try to change to the page where i using googleMaps, the app will simple got closed.

(I think was android studio gradle opened and attempted to upgrade and this break the plugins functionality).

Other thing that was changed is that previously when i run command:

```
ionic cordova build android -c
```

the output APK looks like:

```
app-debug.apk
```

now when i run this command the name is something like:

```
android-debug.apk
```

This thing means that I will never be able to run command:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

because the installation apk name that is recognized for the command is app-debug, not android-debug.

This is the output, but if i try to remove android platform and add it again, an error happens if y try to run:

```
ionic cordova build android -c
```

this is the output that i'm getting using android 6.4.0:

```
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: V6
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to C:\xampp\htdocs\MyQuestApp\myquestapp\platforms\android\build.gradle
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to C:\xampp\htdocs\MyQuestApp\myquestapp\platforms\android\cordova-android-support-gradle-release\starter-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: V6
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to C:\xampp\htdocs\MyQuestApp\myquestapp\platforms\android\build.gradle
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to C:\xampp\htdocs\MyQuestApp\myquestapp\platforms\android\cordova-android-support-gradle-release\starter-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\angela\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
+-----------------------------------------------------------------
| cordova-android-support-gradle-release: 27.+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------
Configuration 'compile' in project ':' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
config.xml
../config.xml
../../config.xml
preference = 10
name = ScrollEnabled, value = false
name = android-minSdkVersion, value = 19
name = BackupWebStorage, value = none
name = SplashMaintainAspectRatio, value = true
name = FadeSplashScreenDuration, value = 300
name = SplashShowOnlyFirstTime, value = false
name = SplashScreen, value = screen
name = SplashScreenDelay, value = 3000
name = AndroidPersistentFileLocation, value = Compatibility
name = GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY, value = AIzaSyAP7l8T_EYdETsJfpwtotTE5iDCoMebJlY
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_1v9usha2n179nr38j15ea2rs.run(C:\xampp\htdocs\MyQuestApp\myquestapp\platforms\android\build.gradle:146)
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:platformAttrExtractor UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:validateSigningDebug
:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:cdvBuildDebug UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2m 50s
44 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 43 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s):
        C:/xampp/htdocs/MyQuestApp/myquestapp/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/debug/android-debug.apk
```

But this is the different output that i'm getting if i uninstall platform android and re-add it with:

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Output when i run ionic cordova build android:

```
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: V7+
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to C:\xampp\htdocs\MyQuestApp\myquestapp\platforms\android\app\build.gradle
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to C:\xampp\htdocs\MyQuestApp\myquestapp\platforms\android\cordova-android-support-gradle-release\starter-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: V7+
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to C:\xampp\htdocs\MyQuestApp\myquestapp\platforms\android\app\build.gradle
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to C:\xampp\htdocs\MyQuestApp\myquestapp\platforms\android\cordova-android-support-gradle-release\starter-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\angela\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
> Task :wrapper

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 23s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Configure project :app
+-----------------------------------------------------------------
| cordova-android-support-gradle-release: 27.+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
config.xml
../config.xml
../../config.xml
../../../config.xml
preference = 10
name = ScrollEnabled, value = false
name = android-minSdkVersion, value = 19
name = BackupWebStorage, value = none
name = SplashMaintainAspectRatio, value = true
name = FadeSplashScreenDuration, value = 300
name = SplashShowOnlyFirstTime, value = false
name = SplashScreen, value = screen
name = SplashScreenDelay, value = 3000
name = AndroidPersistentFileLocation, value = Compatibility
name = GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY, value = AIzaSyAP7l8T_EYdETsJfpwtotTE5iDCoMebJlY

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
> Task :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
> Task :app:preDebugBuild
> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript
> Task :app:checkDebugManifest
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :app:prepareLintJar
> Task :app:generateDebugSources
> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues
> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
> Task :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugRFile
> Task :CordovaLib:prepareLintJar
> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
> Task :CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug

Note: C:\xampp\htdocs\MyQuestApp\myquestapp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemCookieManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues
> Task :app:generateDebugResources
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:processDebugManifest

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
23 actionable tasks: 23 executed
> Android resource linking failed
  C:\xampp\htdocs\MyQuestApp\myquestapp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:34: AAPT: error: resource xml/network_security_config (aka io.ionic.starter:xml/network_security_config) not found.
  error: failed processing manifest.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 5s
C:\xampp\htdocs\MyQuestApp\myquestapp\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: C:\xampp\htdocs\MyQuestApp\myquestapp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemCookieManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  C:\xampp\htdocs\MyQuestApp\myquestapp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:34: AAPT: error: resource xml/network_security_config (aka io.ionic.starter:xml/network_security_config) not found.
  error: failed processing manifest.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 5s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

The reason i want to delete the android studio project located in ionic project is that i think that the ionic builder is not using the ionic project configurations, ionic is using android studio project configs now to make the apk build, and i think this is the error, but i don't know about any command that 'removes' the android studio project config of an ionic project.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you build your apk from command line or android studio, it should work. Delete the `.gradle` folder from your project and reinstall (remove and install) imagepicker and googlemaps plugin and try.

Comment: did that steps but doesn't works... :c